# Is there a way to simulate low-dpi rendering in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I'm normally develop on hi-dpi machines (a Macbook Pro, 2018 MBA, iPhone, Pixel 2 XL). Often I'm styling something or drawing a diagram and I need to know how it's going to look when displayed on a low-dpi machine (pre 2018 Macbook Air, majority of PCs, etc...)

I tried using Chrome's devtools device emulation and it let's you set a devicePixelRatio but it's still actually rendering text and SVGs and styles in hd-dpi. (Not really sure what that setting is doing. I made to custom settings, one 1280x780 dpi = 2, and another 1280x780 dpi = 1 and switching between them changes nothing. My guess is it only changes what "windows.devicePixelRatio" and maybe what images load if using `srcset` and css media queries.

Is there a way to simulate low-dpi in Firefox or Chrome? Basically to get the browser to render at 1/2 the resolution and then expand with nearest neighbor filtering. I realize it will not be a perfect representation but my hope is it's good enough to check that thin lines in a diagram for example are still readable.

Answer (score 3):

Well I figured out one way, at least on Mac.

Turn on OS Zoom in Settings under Accessibility

[image]

Be sure to **un**check "Smooth images". Then in Chrome or Firefox set the zoom level to 50% and turn on the OS level zoom <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>

This does a pretty good job of looking like a low-dpi display.

Comment: _Delightfully devilish, gman!_ It works perfectly. The next best solution would be to change the display resolution to `@1x` using special tools, but the Mac will smooth them, so you won't be able to see the pixels perfectly.